How to get Nginx to return the MP3 mime/type for custom error pages
I'm trying to configure Nginx as the backend for an accessible-first audio content server, all is working perfectly except for handling error conditions outside the application, i.e. falls back to Nginx error pages.
If an error is handled inside the application, the application will return audio files that correspond with the application error. If the error occurs outside of the application Nginx will serve up its 404 or 403 HTML page.
Instead, I would like Nginx to return a custom error MP3 such as 404.mp3, 403.mp3 which would state the error and provide the user with instructions on what to do next etc.
I have correctly configured Nginx to return the relevant MP3 file as a custom error page, but because it doesn't rewrite the URL and append the ".mp3" filename extension, the mime/type isn't provided in the response header so it is not handled properly by the browser. If the I navigate manually to the custom error MP3, the browser correctly identifies it as an audio MP3 file and automatically plays it.
Current Nginx configuration is:
    server {
        server_name _;

        include mime.types;
        root /app;

        index index.html;

        location ^~ /_errors/ {
            root /app/content/mp3/http_errors;
            allow all;
        }

        location / {
            error_page 404 /_errors/404.mp3
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }

Currently, if I navigate to htttp://app/non_existent_url then it correctly returns the 404.mp3 file but it does not change the URL or specify the mime/type.
